# How to manually add a path to be resolved in eslintrc

Tags: webpack, eslint, resolve

I have a folder in my project `main` that I am resolving like a module. For instance `import x from 'main/src'` imports `main/src/index.js`. This is done through webpack's resolve alias configuration.

An issue I am having is getting rid of the errors via eslint. I know eslint provides a webpack resolve plugin, however, I've been having trouble getting it to work. I suspect it is because I am on webpack 2 and using es6 in my webpack config files.

Is there a manual way to write a resolve setting that fixes this problem for my eslint?

---

The only other hack I've seen work is using `import/core-modules` but then I have to list out every folder in the subdirectory tree `main/src/bar`, `main/src/foo`. This would not be ideal.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I think the link below helps you.
You can add resolving directories by using config.

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers

For example, if you want to resolve `src/`, you can write like below on `.eslintrc`.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then ESLint resolve from src directory.
You can require `src/hoge/moge.js` by writing `const moge = require('hoge/moge');` and ESLint knows it.

Comment: ESLint configuration is invalid:
 - Unexpected top-level property "settings".

Comment: Great solution for resolving in WebStorm IDE, but webpack is trying to install these modules:
`import {STATE_FICHE as initialState} from 'data-srtuctures/fiche';`
webpack says:
`Installing data-srtuctures...` and fails. Is there any solutions for Webpack2?

Comment: This solution works for files within src. However eslint could not resolve path for files at root. How can that be resolved?

Answer (score 22):

Too late to see this question. Actually, there is already a resolver named [eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias) that implements this functionality with the below setting.

```
{
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'alias': [
        ['main/src', './main/src']
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I was facing similar problem: `ESLint` was not able to resolve the modules imported relative to instruction `"baseUrl": "src"` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Managed to solve the problem in a similar to the marked as a solution answer, except I had to add the extensions array. So I added the following to my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        paths: ['./src']
      }
    }
  },
```

Hope this helps someone. The source of my solution is actually the [package's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node).

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with webpack. I installed eslint-import-resolver-webpack and updated .eslintrc thusly

```
{
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": "webpack"
    }
}
```

Comment: where is all the rest of the path's configuration? this pasted code is enough?

Comment: The path config is the standard webpack alias config. In the webpack config file under resolve: { alias: {...} }. This code just points eslint to use webpack's path config instead of its own.

Comment: This code also assumes that your webpack config is in the default webpack.config.js file. If it's different (like if you have a separate dev/prod configs), you can specify a webpack file like this: 

"settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "webpack": {
                "config": "webpack.dev.config.js"
            }
        },
        ...

Answer (score 11):

My work settings
`.eslintrc.js`

```
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: ['.'],
      },
    },
  },
```

and `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Wow... why isn't that the default -.-

Comment: Cool worked for .eslintrc.js... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For my case I was getting eslint such error in React, when I was trying to import `react-native-svg` package there. I did it since I was using one code-base for both React and React-Native. So fo me the following code worked in `.eslintrc`:

```
"import/no-unresolved": [
  2,
  {
    ignore: [
      'react-native-svg'
    ]
  }],
```

Hope this will help someone else

Answer (score -1):

As Zip184 stated in coment above
If you have multiple webpack configurations, you have to specify the path to the config

```js
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "webpack": {
      "config": "webpack.common.js"
    }
  }
}
```