# ESLint import module not recognized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've added new module in my React-Native project.

When I use this module, import works nicely, but ESLint show below error :

`2:26  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'react-native-quick-actions'  import/no-unresolved`;

I don't understand why I am getting this error ... import works and my module is also present in my `node_modules` folder.

My import : `import QuickActions from 'react-native-quick-actions';`

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Issue lies in .eslintrc. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769880/how-to-manually-add-a-path-to-be-resolved-in-eslintrc) may help you.

Comment: Hi tarzen ! I've try to add import module, but same result :/