# React:Unable to resolve path to module and intellisense in my own typescript react moudle does not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellisense

I have created my own env module following this repo:

https://github.com/codeBelt/Custom-Environment-Variables-Setup

in the index file, I import the environment module and I got an error from typescript ( not a compilation error, the code is working)

```
import environment from 'environment';
console.log(environment.api);
```

**2 issues:**

1. environment.  and typescript don't manage to complete it ( inteliisense)
2. i got "Unable to resolve path to module 'environment'.eslint(import/no-unresolved)"

I have the following files :

enviornments/Base.ts

```
export default function baseEnv(baseUrl: string) {
  const baseAPi = window.config.API_URL || baseUrl;

  return {
    api: {
      settings: `${baseAPi}?action=get_settings`
    },
    isProduction: true,
    isDevelopment: false,
    isTesting: false
  };
};

export type Environment = ReturnType<typeof baseEnv>;
```

enviorments/production.ts

```
import environment, { Environment } from './base';
/*
 * base.ts is the default environment for production.
 * You shouldn't have to override anything.
 */

const baseApi = 'http://api';
const env = environment(baseApi);

const productionEnv: Environment = {
  ...env
};

export default productionEnv;
```

enviornments.d.ts

```
declare module 'environment' {
  import baseEnv from 'environments/base';

  const value: ReturnType<typeof baseEnv>;

  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to manually add a path to be resolved in eslintrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769880/how-to-manually-add-a-path-to-be-resolved-in-eslintrc)

here is the solution

1 - open eslintrc.

2 add settings object as follows:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    }
},
```